# Replace Display image by HTML5 Iframe module in magento (All Views)

Tags: html, magento, iframe

I am looking to replace the main images of my products with a HTML5 Music player, can anyone give any guidance on how to do this? Target site is http://www.wemakedancemusic.com

Embed player will be like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F63224064&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=ad0606"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The path to the main image template is

```
 /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
```

Then copy it to your local theme template folder and update as needed with the above player code.

(Assuming that all your product page will play same track)

Comment: i do need different tracks on all products, it have to be fully integrated so i can built my products and insert the iframe code in every product page and it will translate with the player playing the desired audio sample...

Comment: You could create a text field attribute (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXvP9Pl7PDM) that store the url/trackid of the song. To get the  url/value for each song in the media template take a look @   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661920/accessing-magento-custom-attribute e.g ... src="http ://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getSongUrl());?>&amp;auto_play... (assuming that the field in the admin is call song_url)